# Android - The bitmap in the PDF Changes size when PDF saved

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap, vudroid

I am trying to draw some bitmap in a pdf and then saving that **pdf** in devices like Note 3/Nexus 7(2013) and other MDPI devices.

Library Used : **VuDroid**

Code used to draw the bitmap :

```
mBitmap = mGesture.toBitmap(
                            (int) (((mGesture.getBoundingBox().width() / 4.0f) + component
                                    .getSize() * 2.5f) * component.getZoom()),
                            (int) (((mGesture.getBoundingBox().height() / 4.0f) + component
                                    .getSize() * 2.5f) * component.getZoom()),
                            0, component.getColor());
            Log.e("Document Viewer", "Setting bitmap 1 else : "+mBitmap.getWidth() + " , " +mBitmap.getHeight());
        }
        if(mBitmap != null){
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        Log.e("Document Viewer", "Setting bitmap 2");

        RectF regionRect = new RectF(component.getLeft() - (mBitmap.getWidth() / 2.0f), 
                    component.getTop() - (mBitmap.getHeight() / 2.0f), 
                    component.getLeft() + (mBitmap.getWidth() / 2.0f), 
                    component.getTop() + (mBitmap.getHeight() / 2.0f));



component.setRegion(regionRect);
component.setAspectSize(component.getSize());
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, regionRect.left, regionRect.top, new Paint());
component.setFinalBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Code to Save the PDF after drawing the bitmap:

```
PdfImportedPage page;PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
                PdfContentByte content;Rectangle rectangle;
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos;Image img;

bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
                                    component.getValue().getFinalBitmap().compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , bos);


img = Image.getInstance(bos.toByteArray());

img.scaleToFit(((img.getWidth() / component.getValue()
                                                    .getZoom()) * component
                                                    .getValue().getAspectRatio())
                                                    / rotatedRatio,
                                            ((img.getHeight() / component
                                                    .getValue().getZoom()) * component
                                                    .getValue().getAspectRatio())
                                                    / rotatedRatio);



    img.setAbsolutePosition(absX, absY);
    content.addImage(img);
    bos.flush();bos.close();
```

Attached screenshots for Note 3 and MDPI Emulator.

Note 3/Nexus 7(2013) : While Drawing :

> [image]

Note 3/Nexus 7(2013) : After Saving:

> [image]

MDPI : While Drawing :

> [image]

After Saving:

> [image]

**Note: The Bitmaps before and after saving in other devices is similar.**